# Converting a String to an Integer so that the number can be used in nested if statement

Tags: python

I am new to python and was playing around. I noticed my code was not reading the last two if statements in my code even though the condition was met.

```
  print("Welcome to the Love Calculator!")

name1 = input("What is your name? \n")

name2 = input("What is their name? \n")

name3=name1 + name2

name4=name3.lower()

t=name4.count("t")

r=name4.count("r")

u=name4.count("u")

e=name4.count("e")


counter1= t + r + u + e

l=name4.count("l")

o=name4.count("o")

v=name4.count("v")

e=name4.count("e")

counter2= l + o + v + e

temp=str(counter1) + str(counter2)

lovescore=int(temp)

if lovescore> 10 or lovescore>90:

  print(f"Your lovescore is {temp}, you go together like coke and mentos")

elif lovescore>=40 and lovescore <=50:

  print(f"Your lovescore is {temp}, you are alright together")

else:

  print(f"Your lovescore is {temp}")
```

Comment: `lovescore> 10 or lovescore>90` is redundant. For every `x>90`, the inequality `x>10` trivially holds true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is not working is that your first if evaluates everything above 10 as valid.

I included some changes in naming and overall structure to show you how I would have done this script. Those are basic changes just to maybe help you on the way.

```
print("Welcome to the Love Calculator!")
name_1 = input("What is your name?\n")
name_2 = input("What is their name?\n")
names = name_1+name_2
names = names.lower()

count_1 = 0
for letter in 'true':
    count_1 += names.count(letter)

count_2 = 0
for letter in 'love':
    count_2 += names.count(letter)

temp = f"{count_1}{count_2}"
love_score = int(temp)
if love_score > 90:
    print(f"Your lovescore is {temp}, you go together like coke and mentos")
elif 40 <= love_score <= 50:
    print(f"Your lovescore is {temp}, you are alright together")
else:
    print(f"Your lovescore is {temp}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Any expression that evaluates to `True` for your elif statement will also evaluate to `True` for your if statement. Therefore, your elif statement (or else, for that matter) never executes.

In other words, any number between 40 and 50 is also greater than 10, so it's covered by the if statement. You'll need to modify your if condition if you expect your elif and else statements to ever possibly execute.